# My login admin dosn't working after migration database from mysql to postgresql

Tags: postgresql, codeigniter, authentication, codeigniter-3, postgresql-9.2

i have problem and i'm new in codeigniter with postgresql, i have a problem when i'm migration database from mysql to postgresql, after that my login admin page dosn't work.

Anyone has an idea?

Thanks.

[image]

this my config database in CI.

Comment: Please read the SO guide on how to ask a question. https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```
$db['default']['dbdriver'] = 'pdo'; //set driver here
```

Accept it if works

Comment: but my setting in config database 'dbdriver' => 'postgre' ? i can use this setting.

Comment: in my login page, when i'm trying fill my username and password. nothing error message. just don't want redirect to my home admin page.

Comment: Edit your question and add controller file or config file so that we can check it..also check the way how you descrober your questions byn using quotes and block quote..

Comment: i can't add image more, because my ratings must 10 star.

Comment: no need to add images just add in text area...Also 
please stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask